# I want only the authorized users to view their images on Akamai. Can this be achieved?

Tags: image, authentication, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, akamai

Currently in my system, all the private images which are behind authentication are being served from my backend application server. All other non-private images are being served directly from CDN (Akamai).

Flow to serve private images is like this

Client browser -> Application Server -> Authorization -> Return Image bitmap to browser

I want to use CDN for private images also since it is putting heavy load on my application servers. Please suggest how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use Akamai's EdgeAuth tokens to do a form of authorisation at their edge server. This allows you to specify an ACL within the token to provide clients with appropriate access, e.g.

```
"/public/*"
```

would allow access to all images that you serve up under /public

```
/client123/*
```

Would allow only access to images served up under /client123

You can also combine these and build up any combination:

```
/client/*|/public/*
```

etc.

This does mean you need to be able to segment your images by route in this way, it can get complex if there is a lot of unpredictable crossover in terms of what clients can access.

The flow for serving this to your client depends a bit on how your client works, you can tab the token onto the image URL itself or serve it up in a cookie (the name of which you configure with Akamai). Tokens are secured via a HMAC signature so they can't be tampered with and you can set as small a window as you like for their validity.

Latest info/code/samples are linked from [this article](https://community.akamai.com/community/media-delivery/blog/2014/12/22/akamai-edgeauth-token-205-java-library-tips), this can be used from .NET and other tech as well as Java. There's also [this node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/akamai-auth-token).

If the above doesn't work for you, it's also possible to have Akamai always validate (i.e. authorise) with your backend, but serve up the asset from the CDN. This obviously removes some of the benefit of using the CDN but it can be beneficial in special cases for a small percentage of your traffic if necessary.

Comment: Hi @Matt, can you put some link describing the solution form your last sentence? I'm looking exactly for this kind of solution and really cannot find anything...

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, it’s a while since I had to do this but I seem to remember it’s basically a setting in the control panel, I discussed it with an account manager and another internal team at the time. You can also set up extra protection between Akamai and your origin, eg cert based auth.

Answer (score 0):

Use Auth 2.0 behavior in akamai. You can find more details in there documentation.