# Serving some files from Azure CDN to only certain users

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Suppose I have a website that is served by an Azure CDN endpoint (via files that have been uploaded to blob storage).

I want the *minified website content* to be available to everyone -- that part is easy, since that's what the CDN does by default.

Ideally, I would also have the sourcemaps available on that same CDN (so that the default behavior of `//# sourceMappingURL=0-8d1d0e3cc4594b2c2758.js.map` within my JS files would "just work").  However, I'd like for those sourcemaps to only be served to a subset of users.

Is there a way of accomplishing this scenario?  I'm happy to defined "subset" in any way that would make this scenario work (e.g., being connected to a certain VPN or being in a certain IP-address range; or using Fiddler to set a secret header; etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. Just as an idea: Is it viable for you to have two live environments you publish to? One being the public one, the other environment with sourcemaps available BUT only accessible to a certain IP range for example?

Comment: @Ozone, having two environments would introduce a number of complications in our particular setup... so while technically possible, it would be very undesirable.  Would love to hear if there's a way to do it with the single CDN endpoint.

Comment: Hi @ MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft. Please can you describe your use case in more detail? I think it would be of help to better understand your problem.

Comment: If you need security around this, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823097/i-want-only-the-authorized-users-to-view-their-images-on-akamai-can-this-be-ach/44899901?r=SearchResults#44899901) may be useful, although the answer I there wasn’t done through azure so not sure if the configuration is a one to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what you need is to build a system that, in production, allows to offer sourcemaps to a certain group of users, for instance, a team of developers, but not to everyone, the sourcemaps should not be publicly accessible.

There are different alternatives that can help achieve this goal.

On the one hand, we can try to use a rules engine that analyzes the received HTTP traffic and offers one or the other response depending on the criteria deemed appropriate.

These rules engines allows you to customize how HTTP requests are handled, by defining a set of possible match condition(s) on the incoming requests, and actions to be performed if the match condition(s) apply.

Azure CDN provides two types of rules engines, one [standard rule engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-reference) for Azure CDN from Microsoft, and [other premium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference) from Verizon, which provide more advanced features.

How you use these rule engines depends largely on how you need to identify your user group and what you want to do to condition the response offered by your application to a sourcemap request.

For instance, one of the standard rule engines [match conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-match-conditions) - also available in the premium rule engine - is the [remote IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-match-conditions#remote-address) where the request comes from: maybe it could be a good criterion to discriminate between your different subsets of users.

Or, as you suggested with the use of Fiddle, you can analyze incoming [request header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-match-conditions#request-header) in search of a custom one.

The Azure CDN Verizon Premium rule engine provides more advanced [match conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-match-conditions) based in browser, device type, etcetera.

Once the users have been identified, the system must consider the action to take depending on whether they belong to one or another group.

Both the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-actions) and [Verizon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features) rules engines provides that could be relevant for this purpose.

I think that the best option, if you can use the [Verizon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features) rule engine, will be to [deny access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#access) to the HTTP requests send by users that does not belong to the group allowed to access the sourcemaps.

Other options, although I think more difficult to implement if your are working with webpack and SPA, can be [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-actions#url-redirect) the requests received from one subset of users to certain files which contains the sourcemaps - or to different `index.html` pages if you are using SPA in your frontend, each with different js and css resources, with sourcemaps or not -, or [rewrite the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-actions#url-rewrite) to directly deliver a different set of files.

Another possible action could be to not include the inline sourcemap location in your minified files and to take advantage of the capabilities to [modify response headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-actions#modify-response-header) and `Append` a [`SourceMap` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/SourceMap) that points to the actual sourcemaps instead. This header will only be sent for the desired user group. Again, depending of how you are building your frontend it could not be an easy task.

Finally, if you are using Webpack and the [`SourceMapDevToolPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/) to build your frontend, you can use the `publicPath` option to point, in production, your sourcemaps to a non public, more developer oriented, URL location. This is the approach followed in [this article](https://itnext.io/using-sourcemaps-on-production-without-revealing-the-source-code-%EF%B8%8F-d41e78e20c89). I think this approach is also worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you, a lot of good options here!  Will try out one or more of the approaches when I get a chance, and will report back once I've had a chance to implement it.  Also, thanks for the edit and added explanations, that's really helpful!

Comment: You're welcome Michael. I'm happy to hear that the answer was helpful. Please, if you think that I can be of any help, don't hesitate to contact me again, I'll be glad to help you.